# Trouble installing Tensorflow with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I'm attempting to install tensorflow by using pip in powershell. I am on windows 10 and am not using a virtual environment. (My appologies for the formatting, I've had to manually add the linebreaks.)

Here is the output from powershell as I check which versions of pip and python I have:

```
PS C:\Users\User> py --version  
Python 3.7.8  
PS C:\Users\User> pip3 --version  
pip 21.3.1 from C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

Finally, here is the output as I try to install tensorflow using pip

```
PS C:\Users\User> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow  
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable  
Collecting tensorflow  
    Downloading tensorflow-2.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (430.8 MB)
       |███████                         | 97.8 MB 34 kB/s eta 2:39:15 ERROR: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)  
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\http\client.py", line 457, in read  
    n = self.readinto(b)  
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\http\client.py", line 501, in readinto  
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)  
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto  
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)  
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into  
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)  
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read  
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)  
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out  

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper  
    status = run_func(*args)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper  
    return func(self, options, args)    
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 339, in run  
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir    
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
 packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 93, in resolve  
    collected.requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 482, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 349, in resolve  
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria  
    if not criterion.candidates:  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__  
    return bool(self._sequence)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__  
    return any(self)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    version=version,  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 287, in __init__
    version=version,  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()    
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 292, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 528, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    link, req.source_dir, self._download, self.download_dir, hashes  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 217, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes,  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 94, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 145, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 144, in iter
    for x in it:  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 87, in response_chunks
    decode_content=False,  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)  
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__  
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)  
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")  
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: Try installing in a virtual environment.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Tauqeer.

This did not fix my problem.

I am now attempting to reinstall Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set socket timeout to a higher value:

```
pip3 install -U --upgrade --timeout 10000 tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when try to install pandas

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

when use

```
pip3 install -U --upgrade --timeout 10000 pandas
```

it works
thanks